# Cannot see Chromedriver.exe in the downloaded folder

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I tried to download chromedriver_win32.zip from the site: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=101.0.4951.15/. When I opened the folder, I could only see chromedriver.app (this is the only thing I saw in the folder), but not chromedriver.exe. I clicked the chromedriver.app, and saw a message saying: Windows cannot complete the extraction. The destination file could not be created.

Can anyone help me to understand what it means and how to find or download the chromedriver.exe? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can download chrome driver from this link:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

When you download your chrome driver will be in download folder.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31925749)